# How can I programmatically move to the next tab in a WPF TabControl?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, tabcontrol

I'm having a bit of trouble with this. I need to add code to move a `TabControl` to the next page. I'm using `System.Windows.Controls.TabControl` available in .Net 4.5. I'm not even sure how I can enumerate the `TabPages`.

An MVVM solution would be ideal, but I can work with a code behind solution. I'd change it a custom behavior or something.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could implement INotifyPropertyChanged in your ViewModel, and then bind the SelectedIndex to an integer property in your ViewModel which notifies on change, something like this:

ViewModel:

```
public sealed class MainViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private int _tabNumber = 0;

    public int TabNumber
    {
        get { return _tabNumber; }
        set
        {
            if (value == _tabNumber) return;
            _tabNumber = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("TabNumber");
        }
    }

    private void ChangeTab(int tabNumber)
    {
        TabNumber = tabNumber;
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    [NotifyPropertyChangedInvocator]
    private void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null) handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525" DataContext="{StaticResource MainViewModel}">
    <Grid>
        <TabControl Height="100" SelectedIndex="{Binding TabNumber}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="108,108,0,0" Name="tabControl1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="200">
            <TabItem Header="tabItem1" Name="tabItem1">
                <Grid />
            </TabItem>
        </TabControl>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: I assume you mean `SelectedIndex`. `TabIndex` is a property on `Control`.

Comment: I sure did, apologies!

Answer (score 2):

You can do this:

```
tabControl1.SelectedIndex++;
```

or can Bind it in XAML